# Cumulative Distribution Functions given 2 independent variables

Tags: statistics, functions

I am having trouble understanding CDFs.

Supposed I have two independent variables X and Y, with their distribution functions F(x) and G(y).

How do I get a CDF of Z, when Z = X+Y, Z =XY, Z=X/Y etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The general solution needs Stieltjes integrals.  Let $H(z)=P(Z\le z)$ for the following three cases.

$Z=X+Y$. $H(z)=P(X\le z-Y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(z-y)dG(y)$,

$Z=XY$. $H(z)=P(X\le z/Y|Y\ge 0)+P(X\ge z/Y|Y\lt 0)=\int_0^\infty F(z/y)dG(y)+\int_{-\infty}^0 (1-F(z/y))dG(y)$

$Z=X/Y$. $H(z)=P(X\le zY|Y\ge 0)+P(X\ge zY|Y\lt 0)=\int_0^\infty F(zy)dG(y)+\int_{-\infty}^0 (1-F(zy))dG(y)$